# Connecting to Cassandra Database Using PHP

Tags: php, cassandra, thrift, phpcassa

I am trying to develop both an Android application and a web front end that will allow me to connect to and query a Cassandra database running on my local host.

I currently have Cassandra 2.0.5, Thrift 1.0.0, JRE 7u51, PHP 5.3.10, Apache 2.2.22

I have scoured the internet for a good explanation of how to get this all set up but have failed to really understand exactly how this all should work. My understanding is that my PHP files on my server will talk to the Cassandra database through the thrift interface and in order to facilitate this most people use higher level PHP libraries. I think this may be where my disconnect is. I don't understand how to install or incorporate these libraries with my project. I have looked at YaCassandraPDO and PHPCassa.

When trying some of these libraries the errors in Apache seem to indicate that the libraries are installed incorrectly or possibly missing components.

I would appreciate any guidance anyone can provide. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome at SO! This site is about answering questions dealing with real problems. It's not to say, that your problem isn't real in the strict sense of the word, but it is too vague to form what's considered a *Good Question™* on SO. Please enhance your problem description, i.e. **what exactly did you try, what errors did you get exactly**, etc. Then it is very likely you will get appropriate answers. - http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 1):

Please check this PHP library http://evseevnn.github.io/php-cassandra-binary/

It is written by me, and how to work with it is similar to the PDO wrapper. Maybe it will suit you.